# Using "neither" without "and" in a sentence

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically correct to combine two negative ideas into one sentence and then start the second part with “neither”, like, "I don’t usually wake up at 6 a.m., neither do I like to wake up at 5 a.m.”?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to say since the 1st phrase relates to your not usually waking up at 6 and the 2nd phrase refers to not *liking* to wake up at 5...but anyway, if you string two negatives together, it's usually structured with the 2nd phrase starting with "nor", for example: "I don't usually wake up at 6 a.m., nor do I like to wake up at 5 a.m.".

Answer (score 1):

It is grammatical. But it is preferable to remove the [*comma splice*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice): replace the comma with a semicolon or a period.

Answer (score 0):

In my view it is grammatical, but rather literary. Some people would object to combining these into a single sentence, but I find it OK.