# Use of neither in beginning of sentence

Tags: sentence, construction

I have come across the following sentence in a paper, and I wonder if it is correct or even just passable English:

> Neither is Islam a constant movement over time."

I would use "nor" here but I became unsure if neither was ok or if both should be avoided?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the EL&U. Your question needs more context. How can we guess what was said before? That will determine if "neither" is used correctly or not. See [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour), it will help you improve your question.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. The reason I did not provide context is that there is none - I should of course have made that clear! The sentence is the first of a new paragraph - nothing was stated before... The previous paragraph explain opinions of Muslims on various subjects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using "neither" without "and" in a sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/200718/using-neither-without-and-in-a-sentence) (Drew's answer, showing that the string beginning with 'neither' may follow a comma, semicolon or full stop [ie be a fresh sentence], but must always following a previous negation.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. Does the previous paragraph have statements about false beliefs about Islam? These could be construed as being negatives that justify the use of _neither_ at the beginning of the paragraph in question.

Comment: Certainly, [Is 'Neither have I wings to fly.' grammatically correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/544127/is-neither-have-i-wings-to-fly-grammatically-correct/544150#544150) is a duplicate (the linked question, about inversion after a negative adverb, is arguably not specific enough).

Answer (score 4):

On the assumption that your sentence follows one with a similarly negative statement about Islam, then starting with *neither* is fine, as is the alternative starting with *nor*:

Garner in the entry on *neither* in *Modern American Usage* (p564) states:

> It is permissible to begin a sentence with *neither*—just as it
> is with *nor*—when embarking on yet another another negative
> subject.

In the entry on *nor* (p573) Garner states:

> *Nor*, like *neither*, may begin a sentence. It must follow either an express negative or an idea that is negative in sense.

Answer (score -1):

"nor" would be more natural to me, but "neither" is fine, I can understand what they mean to say.